# can we say: "The peak is leaded by U.S." (and other variants)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, formal-language

Let's say we are talking about the values of something (between different nations) and U.S. has the *higher* value between them.

Could we say:

> The peak is leaded by U.S. with
>
> U.S. leads with
>
> The peak is by U.S.

Is any of these wrong? What would you use? (where a formal style is preferred).

*note: the values are expressed by a chart using percentages*

**edit**:
*e.g.*: how many citizen use a smartphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use *peak* in this context. *Peak* often represents the highest point over time, particularly when the value rose to a certain point, and then fell again.

For example, in this graph:

[image]

we could say that gas prices *peaked* in 2008, corresponding to the highest point on the graph.

---

In a situation such as the one you described:

[image]

we would say that Europe *leads*, not that Europe *peaks*. We might also say that Europe is *highest* or *at the top*.

One other thing: If we use the word *lead*, the past tense is *led*, not *leaded*. So, if we were talking about this in the past, we would say that Europe *led* all regions in 2008, not that Europe <strike>leaded</strike> all regions in 2008.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you JR

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about points, say, an international competition, and you want to say that the US has the highest points. If so, your second suggestion is the best way to express it. Additionally, you could use any of the following (a few among many possible ways you could say this):

> - U.S.A **leads** with XX points.
> - U.S is in the **lead** with XX points.
> - U.S **leads** 'Country XYZ' by XX points.
> - U.S.A is in the **lead** with XX points.

Any of these could be used formally. I would personally suggest options 1,2 and 4, as the point of concern is only about the US.

**NOTE:** Since you're talking about percentages, the best option would be:

> U.S is in the **lead** with 70% of its citizen using smartphones. (For example)

Comment: No no, not points, just stating some percentages, could be for example how many citizen use a smartphone

Comment: All right, do check my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would say "The USA is at the peak of..." but there are very few things that this holds true for.

"At the peak" means "At the top"

A more likely phrase to use would be "Norway leads the world at..." or "Norway is leading".

A country could be "at the peak of its economic power"

Comment: I'm assuming you're a Norwegian.

Comment: I am not a Norwegian. I just used them as an example. They are usually the one that always tops list of quality of living etc so I felt it was appropriate.

Comment: Oh, is that so ? Cool. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

For a graph showing percentages

> The peak is led by the US

would only be appropriate if you were showing a **trend** which the US could lead

In a bar, pie, or bubble graph it might be better to say

> This peak is mostly from the US
>   The US has the largest share of this peak
>   The biggest percentage comes from the US

This is because you seem to only have one aggregate number (the peak) and then a break down of what's in the aggregate (US, etc.) so the conversation would revolve around who is contributing what to the aggregate number.